# 4G connection PLC

Tags: router

I'm trying to control online a Siemens' PLC. 1200 series.

I'm using a router 4G (TP-LINK) with a SIM card. I created a DynDNS in the router with NOIP.com but I can't communicate with it.

The ports of PLC are open correctly because I'm able to get connection through fiber with other router in my house but not with the SIM card. Also, I already checked that the SIM card is working, I can access the internet with it.

Any idea? What may I be doing wrong?

thank you!!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here, as are questions about home networking and Protocols above OSI layer-4. Also, the manufacturer of a device must offer optional, paid support for a device to be on-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a number of telemetry networks which often are exactly the kind of system you have: PLCs with a 3g/4g router.

Depending on the country and the mobile supplier you may well find that it's not possible to get inbound packets to the router except in direct response to outgoing packets.

In practice we use a number of solutions:

1. Use an outbound-initiated VPN.  I know that some 3g router manufacturers have VPNs for their clients' use; I believe also some PLC manufacturers.  My clients tend to prefer having their own.
2. Some SIM vendors specifically provide "fixed IP address" SIM cards, which do accept incoming packets.  These tend to come from dedicated "M2M" (machine to machine) networking suppliers.
3. If your traffic requirements are simple enough and small enough, the SMS facilities of many 3g/4g devices might suffice.
4. 3g/4g neworking for telemetry can require a lot of work.  Mostly my clients prefer to use fixed lines or as a second choice wifi if it's available.